# Oracle SQL combine table and pivot in version 9i

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a way to combine 2 tables and pivot.  The caveat is that I'm on oracle version 9i which apparently doesn't have the pivot function.  So I'm hoping there's a hacky way I can get around this.  I have 2 tables with the following form:

person table:

```
ID  NAME
 1  John
 2  Steve
 3  Bob
 4  Gary
```

phone number table:

```
ID TYPE NUMBER
 1   1  555-5555
 2   1  555-5556
 2   2  555-5557
 3   2  555-5558
 4   5  555-5559
```

And I want to be able to join the tables as follows:

```
ID NAME  NUMBER_1  NUMBER_2
 1 John  555-5555  
 2 Steve 555-5556  555-5557
 3 Bob             555-5558
 4 Gary
```

Note that there are a number of different `TYPE` values but I only care about 1 and 2.

The current solution I have now is to join the tables on `ID` and use a CASE statement conditioning on `TYPE` to generate `NUMBER_1` and `NUMBER_2`.  The issue is that if I join the tables then there will be 2 rows for Steve.

Comment: Will it be always two `Number's` per `Name`

Comment: In the phone number table there will not always be 2 numbers per ID.  Could be 0, 1, 2, 2+.  In the resulting table, I only care about those 2 types of phone numbers for these people (fyi, they correspond to mobile # and home # --  I don't care about fax # etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` to mimic a `pivot` since you only care about type 1 and 2:

```
select p.id, 
     p.name, 
     max(case when pn.type = 1 then pn.number end) number_1,
     max(case when pn.type = 2 then pn.number end) number_2
from person p
    left join phonenumber pn on p.id = pn.id
        and pn.type in (1,2)
group by p.id, p.name
```

If `null` results are a concern, use an `outer join` instead. (Reading your comments, they are, so I updated the answer).  If you don't want to return people without phone numbers, change it back to an `inner join`.

Note: Using `group by` ensures you only receive a single row per person.  The `conditional aggregation` will allow you to return the home and mobile phone numbers.

---

Per your concern in your comment, this could be included as a subquery as such:

```
select *
from sometable s
   join (
        select p.id, 
             p.name, 
             max(case when pn.type = 1 then pn.number end) number_1,
             max(case when pn.type = 2 then pn.number end) number_2
        from person p
            left join phonenumber pn on p.id = pn.id
                and pn.type in (1,2)
        group by p.id, p.name
    ) t on t.id = s.id
```

Comment: The actual tables I'm joining have a ton of columns.  Is there way a way to get 1 row per person without explicitly having to `group by` every single variable in my table?

Comment: @divide_by_zero -- when using aggregation, any field you are returning in the `select` list that isn't included in an aggregate function has to be included in the `group by` clause.  You could probably use `dynamic sql` to generate the list for you, but I'd recommend typing them out.  Alternatively, you could move this to a `subquery` with just the id and phone numbers, and then `join` to the other tables -- that way you won't have to list out the other fields.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought about joining a sub-table!